# Inserting a distinct entry into db.table results into implicit conversion error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a requirement where I need to insert new entries found in a record into its Master Table and Map the ID of the identifier to the main table

For Instance consider the below example,

```
-- Insert into Category Master if not exists  
INSERT INTO tblCategoryMaster (Category,
                               CreatedBy,
                               CreatedDate,
                               UpdatedBy,
                               UpdatedDate)
SELECT DISTINCT
       (category),
       SERVERPROPERTY('MACHINENAME'),
       GETDATE(),
       SERVERPROPERTY('MACHINENAME'),
       GETDATE()
FROM tblTempDataStaging stg
WHERE category IS NOT NULL
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblCategoryMaster ctg WHERE ctg.Category = stg.category);
```

After executing the select query we get list of distinct entries and every time a new entry is entered in the staging table, the entries are populated in the Master Table accordingly.

Server is not allowing me to insert, its giving me an error saying

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 39
>   Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to nvarchar(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

The data type of the staging table is `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for the relevant fields except datetime for the date fields

Tried using `CONVERT` method but I'm unsure on how do we use it with `DISTINCT` in the picture

Can you suggest how do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem: `SERVERPROPERTY('MACHINENAME')` returns the datatype `sql_variant`:

```
SELECT system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(''MACHINENAME'') AS MachineName',NULL,NULL);
```

The underlying data type is a `nvarchar` (thought it certainly won't be 2GB of storage for the name of a machine!) as can be seen here:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(SERVERPROPERTY('MACHINENAME'),'Basetype')
```

You need to explicitly convert the value. For example:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(256),SERVERPROPERTY('MACHINENAME'))
```

I do suggest you change the data type of your column `CreatedBy`, and I assume `UpdatedBy`,  from `nvarchar(MAX)` to something like an `nvarchar(256)`; you don't need 2GB of characters (about 1 Billion) to store that information.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu this worked. I certainly don't need 2GB of charachters. Noted!